# Android emulator details not listing in Selenium Server for Selendroid

Tags: java, android, android-emulator, selendroid

I am trying a sample project for mobile automation testing in android using selenium. 
From the link http://selendroid.io/mobileWeb.html,  I have started the selenium standalone server and also started the android emulator. 
But the emulator devices is not listing in the supported devices of the selenium server. 
when checked the emulator details in the selenium server 
`http://localhost:4444/wd/hub/status`

```
{"status":0,"value":{"supportedApps":[{"appId":"io.selendroid.androiddriver:0.10.0","mainActivity":"io.selendroid.androiddriver.WebViewActivity","basePackage":"io.selendroid.androiddriver"},{"appId":"org.openqa.selenium.android.app:","mainActivity":"org.openqa.selenium.android.app.MainActivity","basePackage":"org.openqa.selenium.android.app"}],"os":{"arch":"x86","name":"Windows 7","version":"6.1"},"build":{"browserName":"selendroid","version":"0.10.0"},"supportedDevices":[]}}

supportedDevices":[]
```

The supported Devices is listing as empty even after adding the emulator specified from the link http://www.abodeqa.com/2013/05/08/configuring-android-webdriver-in-eclipse/.

How to attach and list the android emulator to the selenium server. 
Any suggestions will be greatly helpful.